# How to make JTextPane only accept number and symbol "." "," (dot and coma) in Java?

Tags: java, jtextpane

How to make `JTextPane` to accept only numbers and the following symbols: `.` , `,` (dot and coma) in Java?

```
private void jTextPane6KeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                            
    char c = evt.getKeyChar();
    if ((Character.isLetter(c) && !(c==KeyEvent.VK_BACKSPACE) || (c==KeyEvent.VK_DELETE))) {
        getToolkit().beep();
        evt.consume();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you use a JTextPane for this? A JTextPane is used to display multiple lines of styled text. In any case you should NOT be using a KeyListener. I suspect you should be using a JFormattedTextField.  The other option is a JTextField with a custom DocumentFilter. These solutions are described in the above link.

Comment: if using jtextformated what I do to declare it?
*I'm still a beginner Please help

Comment: Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Formatted Text Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html) for more information and working examples. Keep a link to the tutorial handy for all the Swing basics.